# How to copy the text of a user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this code. What it should do is ask the user for their name and email, then make a text document that is named the inputted name, and the number 600 and contains the email adrress. But it doesn't work. I have tried many different tutorials and ways of phrasing it, but it won't accept the variables.

```
await message.author.send('We need some information first.\nWhat is your name?')
Name = await message.content
await message.author.send('What is the Email you used for your PayPal account?')
Email = await message.content
with open(Name + '600.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write(Email())
```

Eror:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\HWMonitor\discord bot\bot.py", line 34, in on_message
    Name = await message.content
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: please format the code

Comment: "But it doesn't work." -- please elaborate, and explain what you have done to even *try* to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use await in message.content so it just message.content